# How to recursively walk tree with SimpleXMLIterator?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have this sample code, why my code can find only test3 tag? Where are test and test2?

```
$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new SimpleXMLIterator(file_get_contents('./test.xml'))
);

foreach ($iter as $node) {
    echo "Tag found: ".$node->getName()."\n";
}
```

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
  <test2>
    <test3>dsfds</test3>
  </test2>
</test>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `RecursiveIteratorIterator`, the default mode is JUST to list the leaves(http://php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.construct.php).  If you change the construction to

```
$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new SimpleXMLIterator($xml)
        , RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
```

This indicates to also list the various other parts of the structure and will output...

```
Tag found: test2
Tag found: test3
```